Hitting Mock Server but still getting au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received:
I'm trying to write a Pact test for a new Kotlin Service.
I'm able to hit my mockServer and get a 200 response
However, I keep getting this error
au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received: method: POST path: /requestAccess
at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit.JUnitTestSupport.validateMockServerResult(JUnitTestSupport.kt:110) at au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt.afterTestExecution(PactConsumerTestExt.kt:631)
When I run my code in IntelliJ in debug mode, I'm able to see the request hit my local server and I get a response back as well. I even see mockServer receive matchedRequests = 1, anyone have this issue before?
intellij screenshot
I've running my tests with
   val pactTestRun = object : PactTestRun<Unit> { override fun run(mockServer: MockServer, context: PactTestExecutionContext?) {
as well as
  val result = runConsumerTest(pact, config, pactTestRun)

I'd suggest sharing how your code is setup and any relevant DEBUG logs to help us. There should also be a JUnit report in a folder somewhere, that might also be enlightening to review
